# Using a picker to select an item and add exception handling for that item if it exists

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have AssessmentTypes which is being selected via picker

```
<Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="Medium" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">Assessment Type</Label>
                <Picker Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="AssessmentType" Title="Select an assessment type">
                    <Picker.ItemsSource>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                            <x:String>Objective</x:String>
                            <x:String>Performance</x:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </Picker.ItemsSource>
                </Picker>
```

So 1 course can only have 2 assessments per course. I have that exception handling solved when the user clicked "Add Assessment". I'm trying to check to make sure that when I add an assessment to a course, that only has 0 or 1 assessments already, that the assessment type isn't already present in that course.

I've seen a few examples online but nothing that was helped so far. I didn't give a bunch of info because I wasn't sure what was relevant. Just ask and you shall receive the info.

EDIT - I'm not married to using the picker. If it'll be easier to check if the input string = "Performance" or "Objective" and if those don't already exist, that would be acceptable too. Or if anybody else has anything better

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to have anything to do with XAML or Xamarin or UI at all.  You just want to validate some condition in your data.

You basically want to check if an Assessment already exists for a given Course and Assessment type?

You didn't supply any details of your data structure, but something like this should work

```
using System.Linq;

...

// exists will be true if any Assessments match both criteria, 
// false otherwise
var exists = Assessments.Any(a => a.CourseID == CourseID 
                             && a.AssessmentType == AssessmentType);
```

Comment: Is there anything special you have to do to access the .Any function?

Comment: Yes, use System.Linq